# How would you write this java code in (idiomatic) scala?

Tags: java, scala, if-statement

```
int increment = 0;

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getParameter(NEXT_SCREEN_PARAMETER_NAME))) {
    increment = 1;
} else if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getParameter(PREV_SCREEN_PARAMETER_NAME))) {
    increment = -1;
} else if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getParameter(LAST_SCREEN_PARAMETER_NAME))) {
  increment = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you'd try to avoid setting up the problem this way to begin with, but if that's what you had to deal with, I think the clearest would be something like

```
def testParam(s: String) = StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getParameter(s))
val increment = (
  if (testParam(NEXT_SCREEN_PARAMETER_NAME)) 1
  else if (testParam(PREV_SCREEN_PARAMETER_NAME)) -1
  else if (testParam(LAST_SCREEN_PARAMETER_NAME)) Int.MaxValue
  else 0
)
```

Comment: `def testParam(s: String) = StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getParameter(s))` - nice!

Comment: @Fabian - Your answer was perfectly sensible also; I wouldn't have bothered adding my answer if I'd seen yours.  (I typed mine up, then had to go AFK, and then hit send when I got back.)

Comment: Your first line was the missing part I was trying to think up, and made my answer obsolete - so I'm glad you didn't see mine and added yours :-)

Comment: This answer is much better than the others, which needlessly complicate the problem by using functional operations on collections. You should still improve this one by renaming `testParam` to `hasParameter` or similar.

Answer (score 4):

```
val ps = Seq(1 -> NEXT_SCREEN_PARAMETER_NAME,
             -1 -> PREV_SCREEN_PARAMETER_NAME,
             Int.MaxValue -> LAST_SCREEN_PARAMETER_NAME)

val test = StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getParameter(_ : String))
(ps.view map { case (i,n) => i -> test(n) }) collect { case (i, true) => i } headOption getOrElse 0
```

Using scalaz, you can use the *map map* (∘∘) function:

```
ps.∘∘[PartialApply1Of2[Tuple2, Int]#Apply, String, Boolean](test) 
    collect { case (i, true) => i } headOption orZero
```

As always with Scalaz, it's a real shame that scala's type inference cannot infer partially-applied type constructors. Then you'd have:

```
(ps ∘∘ test) collect { case (i, true) => i } headOption orZero
```

Comment: That's a good point. Obviously it will in this case because I will end up with a `Map3`. I have changed to `Seq`

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
val conditions = Seq((NEXT_SCREEN_PARAMETER_NAME,1),
                     (PREV_SCREEN_PARAMETER_NAME,-1),
                     (LAST_SCREEN_PARAMETER_NAME,Integer.MAX_VALUE))
def parameterDefined(p: String) = StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getParameter(p))
val increment = conditions.find(x => parameterDefined(x._1)).map(_._2).getOrElse(0)
```

This defines the proper increment value for each parameter, finds the first defined parameter, extracts the increment value yielding 0 if no match was found.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly modifed version of Geoff's ansver

```
object ScreenParam { 
  def unapply(kv:Tuple2[String, Int]) = 
    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getParameter(kv._1))) Some(kv._2) else None
}

val conditions = Seq((NEXT_SCREEN_PARAMETER_NAME,1),
                         (PREV_SCREEN_PARAMETER_NAME,-1),
                         (LAST_SCREEN_PARAMETER_NAME,Integer.MAX_VALUE))

conditions.collect{ case ScreenParam(value) => value}.getOrElse(0)
```